# Convert time column to integer in Big query

Tags: time, google-bigquery, integer

How can I convert an entire time column to integer in Big Query?
I have hours/min/sec and I want it in seconds.
I have tried date_part but apparently it doesn't work.
I can have this column into string type too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

use below as an example

```
select time_diff('19:46:25', '0:0:0', second)
```

Comment: How can I do it for an entire column with thousands of times?

Comment: Use your column name instead of first argument

Comment: What if we have to aggregate such types of columns also

Comment: @vikrantrana - please post your question so we can answer :o)